# Refactor if-else-if structure

Tags: c++, c++11, refactoring

How can I refactor the following C++ code? I am using C++11 in my program

```
void f(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f) {

  // MAX1..MAX6 are constants, N1..N6 are constants
    if( a > MAX1) {
        .. code block 1..
    }
    else if(b > MAX2) {
        .. code block 2..
    }
    else if(c > MAX3) {
        .. code block ..
    }
    else if(d > MAX4) {
        .. code block 3 ..
    }
    else if(e > MAX5) {
        .. code block 4 ..
    }
    else if(f > MAX6) {
        .. code block5 ..
    }
    else if(( a > N1) && ( b > N2)) {
            .. code block 6 ..
    }
    else if(( c > N3) && ( d > N4)) {
            .. code block 7 ..
    }
    else if (( e > N5) && ( f > N6)) {
            .. code block 8 ..
    }
    else if (( a > N1) && ( b > N2) && (d > N4)) {
            .. code block 9 ..
    }
    else if (..some combination of (a > N1) to (f > N6)...) {
            // there are more than 30 such combinations in my code
            .. code block XX ..
    }
    else {
            .... code block ....
    }
```

Comment: Are these conditions even mutually exclusive?  What do you expect to happen if both `a > MAX1` and `b > MAX2` are true?

Comment: I just execute the first block which is true

Comment: And `...code block...`s, are they all different or can you make a function for them?

Comment: The question is very interesting even if each ...code block... is a 1-liner. I was wondering myself whether one could convert logical operations with inequalities into something like a concise switch statement.

Comment: All different. Some common variables but otherwise different.

Comment: I would remove dead `block 9`. But I think that question is too abstract to answer properly.

Comment: @JohnQualis "All different. Some common variables but otherwise different." To me, that would be "the decider" to keep everything as is: if your blocks of code are dissimilar enough, any change would make reading more complicated without shortening the code or making it easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be at most 64 code blocks in the function, each of which can use an anonymous function, or a named one:

```
my_func_array[64] = {
    [CONDITION(1,0,0,0,0,0)] = { codeblock1 },
    [CONDITION(0,1,0,0,0,0)] = { codeblock2 },
     ...
};
```

The macro will basically concatenate the 6 first inputs to an index, essentially translating into:

```
 my_func_array[64] = {
    [32] = { ... },
    [16] = { ... },
 };
```

meaning that you don't have to input the conditions in any particular order...

When running, you have to also evaluate all the conditions:

```
 int condition = CONDITION(a < MAX1, b < MAX2, c < MAX2, ...);
 if (my_func_array[condition])
      my_func_array[condition]();
 else
 {
      // this second block should cover all the other cases
      int condition2 = CONDITION(a < N1, b < N2, c < N3, ... );
      if (my_func_array2[condition2])
          my_func_array2[condition2]();
 }
```

Comment: Some additional macros/templates could fill the don't care values: The order matters -- and especially all the function ptrs between [32..63] point to the same code block.

Comment: This appears to be the closest to the solution. Eventually I used your idea. I was a able to re-factor the if-else-if block by using a std::vector of std::tuples where each std::tuple was made of a std::function<bool()> representing the condition, a std::function representing the code blocks and an int settings. The settings integer was used to key into into a std::map of functionals for some setting some common variables. I ended up using a tuple for each if block.

Answer (score 0):

What you have doesn't seem unreasonable, but if you really wanted to refactor, you could create an enumeration

enum class CaseSelect {CASE0, CASE1, CASE2};

then create a function whcih looks very similar to your current if tree, with each code block returning the appropriate enum.

Then create a case statement using the enums, with the appropriate logic in each

It doesn't gain you much, but it separates the logic of selecting state from the operational logic, which may be benefical for clarity in the case of multi line statements

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly start by making `a` through `f`, `MAX`, and `N` into arrays (Just a starting sketch that I can expand with more information on your conditions, code blocks, and uses):

```
const int MAX[6] = { ... };
const int N[6] = { ... };
const std::function funcs[6];

void f(int in[6])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        if(in[i] > MAX[i])
        {
            funcs[i]();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I would suggest, but `std::function` is an overkill here, IMO. Just use function pointers.

Answer (score 0):

So let's say you have a discrete number N of mutually exclusive integer ranges (xi to yi), and you want to call some block of code depending on which range a given input z is, then:

- you want to use a `std::map` binary tree to store the start of each range and the corresponding lambda.
- call the `std::lower_bound` on z to find the candidate range
- and then check the upper bound of that range against z.
- if inside, call the lambda

This will give O(log(N)) time as compared to O(n) for the big if-else chain.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would get rid of the first 6 branches as [Mark B](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18878081/341970) suggests but

- instead of `break` I would `return`,
- I would simply use functions pointers, `std::function` is an overkill
  here,
- I would use `std::array` and bound checking instead of raw arrays.

Now that the boring cases are gone, I would apply the same pattern to remaining branches but it requires some trickery as those conditions are composites.

I am assuming that `MAX1 > N1`. I hope that is true.

First, I would build a decimal number, encoding *all* the arguments:

```
int arg=10^5*(a>N1?1:0)+10^4*(b>N2?1:0)+10^3*(c>N3?1:0)+10^2*(d>N4?1:0)+10*(e>N5?1:0)+(f>N1?1:0)
```

I would also encode the conditions in a similar fashion. For example: condition `(a > N1) && ( b > N2)` becomes `arg >= 110000`, etc.

As you see, after this encoding, you can eliminate the remaining branches in the same fashion as the first 6 branches.

If efficiency is a major concern, you can do the same trick with powers of two (bitshifts and then use bitmasks). I don't do bit fiddling, so I cannot help you with that, but it works the same way and it is more efficient. Probably just as efficient as having that long if-else if chain what you have now, or maybe even more efficient as you are not repeating the same comparisons.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Very good answer. But encoding all arguments into a single argument would couple my program to these variables and constants. What happens if a new variable and a new constant are introduced later on? Then I might have to change everything all over again.

Comment: I believe with some minor changes I could cater for those kind of future changes. But as I see this and the other answers, refactoring perhaps makes your current code harder to understand. I believe [dasblinkenlight](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877611/refactor-if-else-if-structure/18879385#comment27861144_18877611) is correct in his comment, maybe you should keep the code as it was.

Answer (score -1):

If there are a lot of rules, functions objects (eg: lambdas) could be there for rescue:

I simplified it a bit for demonstrational purposes, only 3 arguments...

And I assume there's a safe value for non-check, in this case, `0` (could live without it, but then it would look uglier).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct Rule {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    std::function<int()> fun;
};

Rule rules[]{
    { 10, 0, 0, []() { std::cout << "First!"; return 0;} },
    { 0, 20, 0, []() { std::cout << "Second!"; return 1;} }
};

int f(int a, int b, int c) {
    for (Rule rule : rules) {
        if ((rule.a == 0 || a > rule.a)
         && (rule.b == 0 || b > rule.b)
         && (rule.c == 0 || c > rule.c))
            return rule.fun();
    }
    std::cout << "Not match!";
    return 2;
}

int main() {
    f(5, 23, 3);
};
```

Comment: WTF. why the downvote? from all the answers this seems to be the most readable and flexible...